# AWS MobileHub : Rename Android / iOS sample project

Tags: android, ios, aws-mobilehub

I am a newbie on AWS Mobilehub. I like how it allows me to create project with AWS configured options. However when I try to build the app (ios/swift/android) it always uses my sample project as project name. And in most of configuration settings for AWS project (like using cognito) I have to use mysampleproject to configure. Is there any way I can generate ios/swift/android code with my project name instead of "mysampleproject". Pardon me if my question is too dumb.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a GOOD question and is a feature we are considering. I'll add BOTH of your requests at +1's.

**Question**:
Is there any way I can generate ios/swift/android code with my project name instead of "mysampleproject"?

**Answer**: 
Not at this time. AWS Mobile Hub project code for iOS/Android are all created with "com.amazon.MySampleApp" identifier or project name. For now, I would create your Facebook/Google and Push using your own project name and identifier then update the Mobile Hub generated quickstart app.

In the "Build" instructions, you'll see project names and identifiers you'll need to change for each of the services you implemented. For example, in the Build > Setup > Facebook Sign-in section for iOS, you'll see you only need to change the Bundle ID = com.amazon.MySampleApp to your own Bundle ID.

I see that this is not as streamlined and that is why we are considering the option to allow you to specify the bundle identifier and package name before the sample project code is generated.

Keep an eye on the [AWS Mobile Development Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=88&start=0) for any new announcements or releases.