# AWS MobileHub instructions not clear

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio

I have read a thread over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333024/aws-mobilehub-rename-android-ios-sample-project/37395028#37395028)(I would have asked this *there* but there are strict answer policies) regarding whether the "mysampleapp" project can be renamed(the answer came out to be no). In that case, I would like to know what these instructions on the AWS Mobile Hub are about:

> Use MySampleApp as a Starter App
>   When you use MySampleApp as a starter app for your own app project, it serves as a starting point for your own App development. Remove the "demo" features, replace the app name and package name, build in your own app logic and user interface, and you're done!
>
> Set Unique App Package Name
>   Please copy this segment of code from the MySampleApp project into your own project.
>
> Android Apps must each have a unique package name, before they can be published to any app store. If you have not already, please make sure you replace "com.mysampleapp" with a unique package name for your app. Note that you may also have to change Activity class names in your AndroidManifest.xml file; Android will look for com.mysampleapp.MainActivity.

(Some code after this)

Thanks for reading!!(No tl;drs please :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. Those instructions are so that you can manually change the package name yourself.

You can rename the package manually by following the instructions you quoted. Dennis' response of "Not at this time" was as to whether we currently support renaming it for you automatically in the Mobile Hub Console.

As Dennis pointed out in the linked reply:

> "This is a GOOD question and is a feature we are considering. I'll add
> BOTH of your requests at +1's."
>
> "I see that this is not as streamlined and that is why we are considering
> the option to allow you to specify the bundle identifier and package name
> before the sample project code is generated.
>
> Keep an eye on the AWS Mobile Development Forum for any new
> announcements or releases."